# Apply a replacement to each 3rd dimension of a 3D array

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I have an mxnxp (3D) array A. I have a 2D matrix B with values ranging from 1:m in the first column and 1:n in the second column. What I'd like to do is NA out the indices that correspond to those given by B in each of the third dimension (heights?). So,

```
for (i in 1:p) {
    A[,,i][B] = NA
}
```

Is there a way to do this without a for loop? I was thinking something like

```
A_NA = apply(A,3,function(x) x[B] = NA)
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  Perhaps `apply(A,3,function(x) { x[B] = NA; x})`

Comment: @akrun Hm that seems to be pretty good! The only thing is that that returns a (mxn)xp 2D matrix that I then have to remake into a 3D array with 

    array(A,dim=c(m,n,p)).But that's easy, I suppose.

Comment: Not sure apply can take 3 as margin, though. It says only 1 or 2 in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to return the `x` and then assign it back to 'A'

```
A[] <- apply(A,3,function(x) { x[B] = NA; x})
```

Checking with the OP's solution

```
for (i in 1:p) {
     A1[,,i][B] = NA
 }

identical(A, A1)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
A <- array(1:40, c(5, 4, 2) )
B <- cbind(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(2, 3, 1, 1))
p <- 2
A1 <- A
```